# how can we create autogenerated custom user id in Express js with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In my documents, I have 3 fields in that docs and now I want to create sequential user id which is auto-generated like we set joining_id as the prefix for all user id prefix then all user id start with that prefix like
`user 1 id is = joining_id1`, `user 2 id is = joining_id2` so on .... like this

my code is

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'A User must have name'],
        unique: true
    },
    joining_id: {
        type: String
    },
    reffral_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'A user must have a Reffral Id']
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it have to be sequential? Mongoose automatically adds a `_id` field to all schemas.

Comment: yes I want it sequential but want another custom field, I don't want by default user id fields which exist in mongoose _id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion is before store user query to your database and gets the length of your current collection then add 1 to that length.

```
const addUser = async () => {
   const totalUsers = await db.collection.count();
   
   const newUser = {
      _id: `joining_id${totalUsers + 1}`,
      ...other keys
   }

   const user = await db.collection.insertOne(newUser)

}
```

May be this will help.